# Check whether a mounted directory is accessible in Linux, without a long delay

Tags: c++, linux, mount

I have a program running on a Linux single-board computer which should automatically check whether a settings file exists on a USB drive that may or may not be plugged in.

I have set USB drives to automount to /media/usbdrive. This is the entry in mount:

```
systemd-1 on /media/usbdrive type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=41,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
```

This works when the USB drive is plugged in, but when it's not plugged in, my program acts poorly. Whenever I try to access the path, and that includes merely checking whether it exists or not using `stat()` or `std::filesystem::exists()`, the code execution halts. No immediate exception or returned error code, just a complete freeze for a long time, so it's unworkable.

This seems to be a property of the mounting itself, because I also see a freeze if I try to access the directory in a raw Linux terminal, not just my C++ code. And the mount entry is still there when the USB drive is unplugged.

How can I solve this problem? Is there some C++ function that can check whether the directory/file is accessible, without simply freezing when it's not?

Comment: Have you tried checking for the presence or absence of `/dev/sd?` when plugging in and removing the drive?

Comment: Can you use `mountpoint /media/usbdrive` command to determine if its mounted or is that still slow?

Comment: Have you tried running `mount` or `mount -v`? Or `lsusb`?

Comment: If none of the above works, you could use a worker thread and if it hasn't returned success or toggled a variable after x milliseconds then assume failure.

Comment: For the record, I didn't find a solution to the original problem per se, but as suggested I simply run mount/umount before and after running my code to make sure that the directory is only mounted if the drive is present (because "mount" fails if not). It is quick either way.